# How to add a word or words to a 2-D array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong. Another question on Stack Overflow said to use `strcpy` and I did but it still won’t work. 
This is the function. Can you guys please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char LeftAlignment(int columnWidth) {
    printf("FIXME: LA");

    char para[20], line[20][20];
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter your text: ");
    scanf("%s", para);

    for (a=0; a!=feof(stdin); a++) {
        for (b=0; c < columnWidth; b++) {
            strcpy(line[a][b], para);
            c = (strlen(para) + 1) + c;
        }
        scanf("%s", para);
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what the function should do.

Comment: `strcpy(line[a][b], para);` this is wrong, maybe it should be `strcpy(line[a], para);`?

Comment: `c` is not initialized. first argument of `strcpy` is of type `char`. `a!=feof(stdin)` does not make sense. function does not return anything.

Comment: @kiranBiradar It would be syntactically correct, but what would be the purpose of `b` then?

Comment: @Osiris Even I'm not sure why op needs 2 for loops. That's why maybe.

Comment: Your code make no sense.It is way too unclear what you want. Besides that, you have many mistakes in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it still won’t work"? Please make a [mcve] to clarify.

Comment: Try using the debugger to see the values of all your variables after each instruction. You should be able to see when things don't go as expected.